# Upon Pageload, Show Checkbox Checked Or Unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ajax, gridview

I have a column in a gridview of checkboxes. I want to be able to display those boxes to be either checked or unchecked according to the corresponding value in the database (currently this column is not bound to any field, I'm having problems with that). Something that has been giving me problems is the fact that I'm using Ajax. when I do AutoPostBack = true, the checkbox appears checked for only a moment, and then when it refreshes everything the check disappears. Any help would be appreciated.

.CS

```
public partial class vieworders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string orderByString;
    private string fieldString;
    private string address;
    private DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         orderByString = orderByList.SelectedItem.Value;
         fieldString = searchTextBox.Text;
         string sqlStatement = "SELECT fName,lName,zip,email,cwaSource,price,length FROM SecureOrders WHERE fName LIKE '%" + fieldString + "%' OR lName LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%'  OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%'  OR email LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR cwaSource LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR length LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR price LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' ORDER BY " + orderByString;
            ////////////////////////////


            System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.
                OpenWebConfiguration("/Cabot3");
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connectionString;

            connectionString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["secureodb"];

        //TEST
            for (int i = 0; i < DefaultGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)DefaultGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBoxProcess");
                if (chkUpdate != null)
                {
                    OrderBrowser.Text += "Test";
                }
            }



            // Create an SqlConnection to the database.
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connection);


                // create an SqlCommandBuilder - this will automatically generate the
                // commands, and set the appropriate properties in the dataAdapter
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                // create the DataSet
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                // fill the DataSet using our DataAdapter

                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "SecureOrders");


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecureOrders", connection);  // might not need this
                SqlCommand bitCmd = new SqlCommand("Select IsNull(processed,0) as processedField From SecureOrders", connection);
                DataView source = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
                DefaultGrid.DataSource = source;
                DefaultGrid.DataBind();
            }


         }

    protected void DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = DefaultGrid.SelectedRow;
        string name = "Name: " + row.Cells[2].Text + " " + row.Cells[3].Text + "\r\n";
       // if (row.Cells[4].Text == "&nbsp;")
        //{
            //address = "Address: " + row.Cells[3].Text + "\r\n         " + row.Cells[5].Text + ", " + row.Cells[6].Text + " " + row.Cells[7].Text + " " + row.Cells[8].Text + "\r\n";

       // }
        //else
       // {
           // address = "Address: " + row.Cells[3].Text + "\r\n         " + row.Cells[4].Text + "\r\n         " + row.Cells[5].Text + ", " + row.Cells[6].Text + " " + row.Cells[7].Text + " " + row.Cells[8].Text + "\r\n";
        //}

        string zip = "Zip: " + row.Cells[4].Text + "\r\n";
        string email = "Email: " + row.Cells[5].Text + "\r\n";
        //string phone = "Phone: " + row.Cells[10].Text + "\r\n";
        //string cctype = "Credit Card Type: " + row.Cells[11].Text + "\r\n";
        //string ccnum = "Credit Card Number: " + row.Cells[12].Text + "\r\n";
        //string ccexp = "Credit Card Expiration: " + row.Cells[13].Text + "\r\n";
        string length = "Length: " + row.Cells[8].Text + "\r\n";
        //string delivery = "Delivery: " + row.Cells[15].Text + "\r\n";
        string price = "Price: " + row.Cells[7].Text + "\r\n";
        string source = "Source: " + row.Cells[6].Text + "\r\n";
        //string joined = "Joined: " + row.Cells[18].Text + "\r\n";
        //string url = "URL: " + row.Cells[19].Text + "\r\n";

        OrderBrowser.Text = name + email + length + price + source;
    }

    protected void CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)cb.NamingContainer;
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            OrderBrowser.Text = "checked";
        }
        else
        {
            OrderBrowser.Text = "unchecked";
        }

    }

    }
```

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="vieworders.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cabot3.custserv.vieworders" %>
```

```
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="orderByList" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="fName" Selected="True">First Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="lName">Last Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="state">State</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="zip">Zip Code</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="cwaSource">Source</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="cwaJoined">Date Joined</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="searchLabel" Text="Search For: " />
        <asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" Columns="30" />
        <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    </div>
<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID = "up" runat="server">



    <ContentTemplate>
    <div style= "overflow:auto; height:150px; width:700px">
    <asp:GridView ID="DefaultGrid" runat = "server" DataKeyNames = "fName, lName, zip"
    onselectedindexchanged = "DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
    autogenerateselectbutton = "true"
    selectedindex="0">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Azure"
    forecolor="Black"
    font-bold="true" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Processed">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxProcess" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged"  runat="server" Enabled="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OrderBrowser" columns="70" Rows="14" runat="server" Wrap="false" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly = "true"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>



</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because when you click on the checkbox, During the AJAX postaback, your `page_load` event fires before `CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged` where your Gridview is binded again.

It should be like...

```
If(!IsPostBack)  // you missed this condition
{
   orderByString = orderByList.SelectedItem.Value;
     fieldString = searchTextBox.Text;
     string sqlStatement = "SELECT fName,lName,zip,email,cwaSource,price,length FROM SecureOrders WHERE fName LIKE '%" + fieldString + "%' OR lName LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%'  OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%'  OR email LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR cwaSource LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR length LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR price LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' ORDER BY " + orderByString;
        ////////////////////////////


        System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration("/Cabot3");
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connectionString;

        connectionString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["secureodb"];

    //TEST
        for (int i = 0; i < DefaultGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)DefaultGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBoxProcess");
            if (chkUpdate != null)
            {
                OrderBrowser.Text += "Test";
            }
        }



        // Create an SqlConnection to the database.
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connection);


            // create an SqlCommandBuilder - this will automatically generate the
            // commands, and set the appropriate properties in the dataAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // create the DataSet
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            // fill the DataSet using our DataAdapter

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "SecureOrders");


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecureOrders", connection);  // might not need this
            SqlCommand bitCmd = new SqlCommand("Select IsNull(processed,0) as processedField From SecureOrders", connection);
            DataView source = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            DefaultGrid.DataSource = source;
            DefaultGrid.DataBind();
        }
}
```

**Edit:** After following your comments, you don't need to iterate the gridiew rows to set the checkbox state. You can either use the RowDataBound event of GridView or directly bind the value. e.g.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxProcess" Checked='<%#Eval("processedField") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged"  runat="server" Enabled="true" />
```

**Update:** Please change the following code with this one

```
 // Create an SqlConnection to the database.
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            connection.Open();                

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SecureOrders", connection);

            // create the DataSet
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            // fill the DataSet using our DataAdapter               
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "SecureOrders");

            DataView source = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            DefaultGrid.DataSource = source;
            DefaultGrid.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: this looks great - the only thing is that the data is not actually being bound to the checkbox here - how can I bind one field to one column in the gridview?

Comment: You are binding the checkbox value in the wrong way, you don't need to iterate all the rows what you are doing currently. You can use either RowDataBound event or directly bind the checkbox value. Check my answer update.

Comment: Okay I've tried this, but I can't figure out for the life of me what I need to put in "ColumnName". I've tried using the name from my table, but it wont' recognize it!

Comment: What is your field name in the DB for checkbox ?

Comment: The field name is called processed.   I've tried referencing it, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Man I got your problem !!! But I will charge $ 100 for that. Is this OK for you ?

Comment: Your problem was, your field name in the DB is Processed but when you are trying to get value using your SQL command, you are using alies it as processedField You have to use your alias instead Processed.

Comment: My fieldname in the database is lowercase "processed". My problem is the command where I create that alias never gets executed - how would I do this?

Comment: Could you try like... Checked='<%#Eval("processedField") %>'

Comment: Http Exception was unhandled by user code: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'processedField'.

Comment: I guess my problem is running this code "SqlCommand bitCmd = new SqlCommand("Select IsNull(processed,0) as processedField From SecureOrders", connection);"  I don't know how to get my checked property to know where to look!!

Comment: Please check update part of the answer, just copy and paste that code after this comment // Create an SqlConnection to the database.

Comment: Then use this to set the checkbox Checked='<%#Eval("processed") %>'

Comment: Okay when I do this, it works, but I have two checkbox columns now - one that I added in before. one of them is clickable, the other is grayed out!

Comment: AH! I don't know how any of this works. *pulls hair out* going crazy over here...