# Set Checked property in asp using Eval

Tags: asp.net, database, data-binding, eval, checked

I have a statement that looks like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxProcess" Checked='<%#Eval("processedField") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged"  runat="server" Enabled="true" />
```

I've been having this problem for a while, and I KNOW it must be something VERY simple...but in my code, where it says `processedField` what EXACTLY goes there? I want it to reference a column from my database, but I don't know how to make that available to this particular part of code.

A second question, does this bind the `CheckBox` column to my field in my database? I want something to be written to the database when this checkbox is checked. For example, when the checkbox is checked, make the value in the `processedField` become a `1` instead of a `0` (it is a bit field).

Comment: Your problem is when you are getting the value from Database. here in your question, I have a long conversation. did you try my last part of my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651566/upon-pageload-show-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked/6651819#6651819

Comment: but in my code, where it says 'processedField'....i don't see your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set AutoPostBack = "true", the "CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged" method then would contain the code that writes the changed value to your database.  However, I'm not 100% confident I understand your question.

Comment: AutoPostBack worked wonderfully this time around - thanks! What I'm trying to do is display the checkbox with or without a check in it when the page loads up depending on what value is stored in this bitfield in my database. So, if the bitfield has a 1 in it, then the corresponding checkbox will appear checked. If it has a 0, then the corresponding checkbox will appear unchecked...